# From list to data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list with this format

```
[{'label': 'Negative', 'score': 0.640342652797699},
{'label': 'Neutral', 'score': 0.6779775619506836},
{'label': 'Positive', 'score': 0.6488891839981079},
{'label': 'Negative', 'score': 0.8951766490936279},
{'label': 'Neutral', 'score': 0.5843858122825623},
{'label': 'Negative', 'score': 0.9183987379074097},
{'label': 'Neutral', 'score': 0.6507250666618347}]
```

I would like to create a data frame with this information, whit a column called sentiment and the other one called score

dataframe:

```
sentiment  *   score
*********************
Negative   *  0.640342652797699
Neutral    *  0.6779775619506836
Positive   *  0.6488891839981079
 ....           ....
```

I am not suure how can I transform my list to a data frama with this structure

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame(L).rename(columns={'label': 'sentiment'})`

Answer (score 1):

you can create DataFrame then rename column name like below:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(lst_dct).rename({'label': 'sentiment'}, axis=1)
```